# Мне 12 лет, я хочу опубликовать игру в плей маркет, как мне платить налог с дохода с игры?

Tags: unity3d, юридические-аспекты, playmarket

Мне 12 лет, я хочу опубликовать игру в плей маркет, как мне платить налог с дохода с игры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы оплатить налог, сначала нужно получить доход.

> 5 мая 2022 года компания обновила страницу помощи. Теперь Google
> сообщила, что функции обновления и загрузки доступны только для
> разработчиков бесплатных приложений. Компаниям и издателям
> порекомендовали отключить подписки и полностью перейти на бесплатную
> модель распространения ПО. Специалисты отмечают, что Google пошла на
> такой шаг из-за невозможности переводить средства на счета
> разработчиков.

Ну оплатить несложно:
[Порядок оплаты налогов для несовершеннолетних](https://rb.ru/opinion/rebenok-nalogi/)